# How can I remove css from a child theme?

Tags: css, filters, hooks, child-theme, parent-theme

I am using the theme `twentyten` as a parent theme for my child theme. I have other stylesheets I want to use and so I'm trying to figure out how to `wp_deregister_style` for the `style.css` sheet that is printed out in the `head` section of the html.

I have checked the global `$wp_styles` variable around the `shutdown` hook and I see the other styles but not `style.css` - how can I get my child theme to stop using it?

I realize the theme name and info has to be stored here - I don't want to delete it, I just don't want it to be `enqueued`

Comment: do you have the line `@import url("../twentyten/style.css");` in style.css of the child theme? - then remove it.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the parent or the child CSS?

Comment: trying to remove all linked styles from showing up in the head - that's anything like <link rel="stylesheet" src="..." />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twentyten has a `header.php` file which has the style.css hardcoded into it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

There is no way to `wp_dequeue_style` because it is never "loaded" with `wp_enqueue_style` in the first place.

To get that out of the header you'll need to edit the twentyten theme (bad idea) or copy the `header.php` file over to your child theme so that it will override the original one and edit the file there (better idea), or as you mentioned, use a different base theme which does not have the `style.css` file hard coded into the `header.php` file, or  if you will be using another stylesheet, use `add_filter()` to override what `stylesheet_uri()` returns with the new file (best idea).

### Notes

Usage: `<?php get_stylesheet_uri() ?>`

- Uses: apply_filters() Calls 'stylesheet_uri' filter on stylesheet URI path and stylesheet directory URI.
- Uses: get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri:

Comment: You don't need to remove that stylesheet link. **Just don't put any styles in the stylesheet.** You're *already using a Child Theme*, so you have **absolute control** over the content of the Child Theme's `style.css` content.

Comment: if it is empty then you should get rid of it. it's an extra HTTP request (check out yslow) and there is in fact no reason for it to be loaded. plus if you enqueue a style you can specify a version number to help flush old styles when a new version of the css is available - something that you can't do with the hard-coded <style> tag. overall removing the hard-coded stylesheet is a good idea.

Comment: That's a separate issue from what the question is asking; namely; how to override the Parent Theme's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the contents of the `style.css` in your child theme with the contents of the stylesheets you have? The `style.css` in your child theme will replace the parent's stylesheet.

Comment: When using a Child Theme, the **Child Theme's** stylesheet is loaded by the header when `<?php get_stylesheet(); ?>` is called. The Parent Theme's stylesheet is **never loaded** when the Child Theme is in use. That's why, in order to port the Parent Theme's styles into the Child Theme, the Child Theme `style.css` calls `@import()` to include the Parent Theme's `style.css`.

Comment: -1 - sorry @Stephen Harris, you're missing the point. I want to keep the styles from being printed in the <head> in the first place. all of the. i'm going to be using http://lesscss.org/ with this theme.

Comment: @ChipBennett - you're on the right track here. if you post that i will accept the answer. I missed that the stylesheet was hard coded into the <head> of the parent theme. guess i should upgrade to twentyeleven because i think all the scripts should really be enqueued and then printed with with wp_head.

Comment: @cwd my comment is simply a clarification of StephenHarris' answer; I consider his to be correct. He's saying the same thing I am, just in a different way (which is why I offered a clarifying comment).